# «Иди по жизни, танцуя!» — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастия

Нужно ли ставить запятую в этих предложениях?
*Иди по жизни, танцуя!

Иди, танцуя!*

Answer (score 2):

Обособление или необособление одиночного деепричастия может зависеть от места, занимаемого им по отношению к глаголу-сказуемому; одно и то же слово в начале или в середине предложения может обособляться, а в конце — нет:

*Не следует делать не думая; Выполняйте не рассуждая; Люди стояли окаменев; Он заговорил оправдываясь; Минут пять все стояли  не шелохнувшись.*

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу так.

**1.** **Иди танцуя** (запятая не нужна) = пританцо́вывай.
[Пританцо́вывать](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/184910) — ***идти танцуя***, а также делать движения, подобные танцу.

**2.** Идти по жизни = жить.
Иди по жизни смело  — живи смело.

Если мы говорим о танцоре или артисте балета (о человеке, для которого танец — самое главное в жизни), то, думаю, правильно с запятой: **Иди по жизни, танцуя**.

Если же речь о человеке, который не имеет никакого отношения к танцам, то глагол ["танцевать"](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-academ-term-79793.htm) приобретает, как мне кажется, переносное значение (танцуй! — жги!), поэтому запятая не нужна.

Иди по жизни смеясь, **иди по жизни танцуя** (как? каким образом?) — иди по жизни свободно, легко, беззаботно, весело.

[Иди по жизни танцуя!](http://decor2.ru/tproduct/241841183-124553513027-otkritka-019-idi-po-zhizni-tantsuya)

Comment: По мне запятая не нужна в обоих случаях, независимо от того, танцор человек или нет.